# Webservice ignores ResponseFormat.Json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to do a simple $.ajax POST to my asp.net Webservice, returning Json. I've tried all the possible solutions out there, without any luck. Am I missing something?

My jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Services/ConfiguratorService.asmx/GetInitialJson",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        if (data != null) {
            alert(data.d);
        } else {
            alert("data undefined: | " + jqXhr + " | " + textStatus);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXhr + " | " + textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

My asmx.cs code:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Gets initial configuration values for Configurator")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public ConfiguratorModel GetInitialModel()
{
    return new Item { Title: "10 units", Text: "Item text..." };
}
public class Item { public string Title {get; set;} public string Text {get; set;} }
```

Update 1:
In my solution, I'm getting back a response, but only as XML. I've tried to reproduce the error in a fresh solution, with no luck. Everything works just fine. .asmx services in both old and new solution actually return the same response. The only difference is that jquery in one of them fails with error: parsererror, unexpected token <

Update 2:
Response header in my old solution is always "text/xml; charset=utf-8".

Update 3:
My web.config has all the entries that are required. Response is still "text/xml; charset=utf-8". Why?

Comment: What are you getting? error? or anything? please specify

Comment: I'm getting the model, just as text/xml, not as application/json as specified in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine helped me out, pointing in  direction. I found out that handlers were asp.net 2.0. The solution was upgraded from 2.0 to 4.0 earlier this year. all I had to do was replace:

```
<add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHadlerFactory, System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
```

with:

```
<add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Good idea is to try removing all of the handlers temporarily, adding only:

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `static` keyword to call method as you have do define static method

```
public static ConfiguratorModel GetInitialModel()
{
    return new Item { Title: "10 units", Text: "Item text..." };
}
```

Comment: The Service is returning the model. Making it static won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have such web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://example.com/")]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class api : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public ServiceResponse<string> SignIn(string _email, string _password) {...}
}
```

and $.ajax call like yours. Everything works fine to me.
Possibly you need to add `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` to you service class. As far as I remember, that is a key to JSON response. 
jQuery call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/api.asmx/SignIn",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({"_password": pwd,
                            "_email": email
                        }),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (res) { }
   });
```

**Edit:**

```
public ConfiguratorModel GetInitialModel()
{
    return new Item { Title: "10 units", Text: "Item text..." };
}
```

This method definition looks wrong. I do not see how you may return `Item` when return type is `ConfiguratorModel`. This must fail on compilation.

Comment: What is in response? Does it contain what it should, but simply in XML format?

Comment: Correct, the model is returned just fine, only as text/xml. I tested my code and web.config configuration in new solution. Return was json. Seems that some old configuration in my other solution is messing up my response, I just don't know which one. :/

Comment: You can try to copy web.config from that new solution and see if it works with your old solution.

Comment: That was the case... <handlers> were asp.net 2.0, not 4.0. Could you post a reply, and I'll mark it as 'Answer'

Comment: You found an answer to your own question, so no problem to post it like an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug with ignoring ResponseFormat.Json, found only such a solution:

File "Data.asmx"

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Data.asmx.cs" Class="WebServiceData" %>

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebServiceData : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void Get()
    {
        string ret = @"{
            ""arg"": {
                ""ReportID"": 1
            }
        }";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", ret.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ret);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```