# Convert data to JSON format

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net, asmx

i have used the `Newtonsoft.Json` for converting data into json format.

I have write the below code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("Get_data",
          new SqlParameter("@Yourid", "5"));

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString()));

    }

    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = "{" + "''mydata''"+":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt) + "}";
    return JSONString;
}
```

So it gives me the below output:

[image]

But i want the output like :

```
{"mydata":[{"id":125},{"id":137},{"id":249},{"id":201},{"id":124},  
      {"id":173},{"id":160},{"id":153},{"id":146},{"id":168}]}
```

So how can i convert to it from xml to json. ?

Comment: What's the difference between the 2 outputs?

Comment: Are you setting the request content type to application/json at the client side?

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz Sorry . please check the image.

Comment: @elvin sorry. Please check the image

Comment: if you are working on webservices see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235928/webservice-ignores-responseformat-json

if you are working on webapi see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Answer (score 2):

I run your solution in a console application and I can clearly see the problem. If you avoid building json manually, the problem will go away. As I don't have database, I have added my data rows manually. Hope that will help.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Data;
namespace Test
{
    class MyDataContainer
    {
        public DataTable mydata { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet());
            Console.Read();
        }
        static string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));

            dt.Rows.Add(1);
            dt.Rows.Add(2);
            MyDataContainer cont = new MyDataContainer();
            cont.mydata = dt;
            string JSONString = string.Empty;
            JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cont);
            //to see your attempt uncomment the blow lines
            //Console.Write("{" + "''mydata''"+":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt) + "}");
            //Console.WriteLine();
            return JSONString;
        }      
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes. you are right. Please check my image in question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your codes, you are already declared that your output is type of JSON, so on the response data it will return a JSON string.

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And you also declared that this is a `ScriptMethod`. My thought is you are testing your app by running your code and accessing the url of the web service - for example http://localhost/test.asmx and clicking the invoke button on your `DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet` method. This approach will really display **JSON** result enclosed on **XML** format. The best way to test your own code is to invoke the web service using something like **jQuery Ajax** or equivalent (client scripts).

You can change your code to something like this to achieve the output you are looking for:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public MyResponse DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("Get_data",
          new SqlParameter("@Yourid", "5"));

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString()));

    }

    MyResponse result = new MyResponse();
    result.mydata = dt;
    return result;
}

class MyResponse
{
    private object _mydata;
    public object mydata { get { return this._mydata; } set { this._mydata = value; } }
    public MyResponse() { }
}
```